# Como verificar se um campo do tipo XML é null ou vazio no SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, xml

Preciso verificar a quantidade de 0,  NULL ou vazio em campos de tipo tipos diferentes, Minha dificuldade é quando se trata de campos do tipo XML. 
Tentei incluir na minha logica a função exist(), mas não sei se é a melhor maneira de fazer essa verificação, usando o código que já fiz antes.

```
/*vérifie si la colonne numérique a des zéros et si la colonne avec des textes est vide (ou ne contient que espaces)*/

if @dataType IN ('int', 'bit', 'smallint', 'numeric', 'float', 'bigint', 'varbinary')
    set @checks = '[' +@colName +']' + '=0'

else if @dataType IN ('varchar', 'char', 'nvarchar', 'date', 'datetime')
    set @checks = ' ltrim(rtrim(['+ @colName + '])) ' + 'like '''''

else if @dataType IN ('xml')




/*vérifie si est nullable et si la colonne est nule*/
if @isNullable = 1
if LEN(@checks)> 0
    set @checks = @checks + ' OR [' + @colName + '] IS NULL '
else
    set @checks = '[' +@colName + '] IS NULL '


set @queryStat = @queryStat + @checks

EXEC sp_executesql @queryStat, @paramDefinition , @cnt = @vides output
```

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa fazer um `if` para o tipo xml; basta verificar se o campo é null. Para isso deve se ter `@isNullable = 1` e entrará nesse trecho que faz a verificação:

```
/*vérifie si est nullable et si la colonne est nule*/
if @isNullable = 1
if LEN(@checks)> 0
    set @checks = @checks + ' OR [' + @colName + '] IS NULL '
else
    set @checks = '[' +@colName + '] IS NULL '
```

Comment: Eu tentei verificar apenas se era nulo, mas obtive o erro abaixo, como se eu nao tivesse feito a verificaçao para o tipo xml

                                                                             **Xml data type is not supported in distributed queries. Remote object 'CTCL-dbpdata24\sql2016.blatuio269_Prd.dbo.tabStagingMessages' has xml column(s)**

Comment: Oi Raquel. O erro não é pq o xml é nulo, e sim que o tipo xml não é suportado em queries distribuídas. Imagino que dentro de `sp_executesql` tenha algo como `SELECT XXX FROM LINK.MinhaBAse.dbo.TabelaX;`. No caso, teria que fazer o cast do xml para outro tipo, mas aí teria que ver a stored procedure.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Vou ter que proceder de outra maneira. Obrigada!